# Chrome inactive tab timeout throttle

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc

By default, Chrome has a minimum inactive tab timeout throttle set to 1 second.

In the company I work, there are several legacy Selenium tests, that use Remote Control.

After last Chrome update (39) we noticed that method `start` of `DefaultSelenium` opens Remote Runner and so opens /selenium-server/core/Blank.html in a separated tab, instead of opening in a new window. So Remote Runner tab gets inactive and test execution gets very slow.

How can I set Google Chrome timeout throttle to a lower value? Or what can I do to Remote Control open /selenium-server/core/Blank.html in a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up changing a function from Selenium htmlutils.js file to force Chrome to open application in a new window.

Before:

`var appWindow = window.open(url + '?start=true', 'selenium_main_app_window');`

After:

`var appWindow = window.open(url + '?start=true', 'selenium_main_app_window', 'menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes');`